# How do I get videos to start playing when I switch between bootstrap tabs?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

How do I get videos to start playing when I switch between bootstrap tabs?

```
$('#tab').on('click', function() {
  $('.active').find('video').each(function() {
    $('#video').play();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can hook to the event that Bootstrap triggers when a tab is shown: `shown.bs.tab`. Then you can call `stop()` on the previous tab's videos, whilst you call `start()` on the current tab's. Try this:

```
$('#tab').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
  // start videos in new tab
  $(e.target).find('video').each(function() {
    this.play();
  });

  // stop videos in old tab
  $(e.relatedTarget).find('video').each(function() {
    this.stop();
  });
});
```

More information on the Bootstrap tab events is available in the [documentaton](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-events)

Comment: I believe both event targets are pointing to the tab (anchor) not the content. So it might be `$('#' + $(e.target).attr('href'))` or something. Please correct me.

Comment: You could be right, in which case it would be better to use a class on the tabs: `$('.tab').on('shown.bs.tab'...`

Answer (score 0):

To add on to rorys answer if you would like to go back to old tabs and resume where you left off you can you `$('#video').pause()`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the ID. jQuery only return single element (will only select the first matched element in the DOM) if you use ID selector. Use this:

```
$('#tab a').on('click', function () {
 $('#tab .active').find('video').each(function (video) {
   $(video).get(0).play();
 });
});
```

Read [this](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).